# How to make object hair particle a texture for low poly mesh

Tags: texturing, particles

I'm modeling a bush for unreal engine.

I'm curious if there is a way to convert my particle system into a texture i can wrap around a 3d model. Or if there is a way to use planes to simulate a high poly model with the particle system.

[image]